# How to perform emergency call while "Android is starting..."

Tags: boot, emergency-calls

Sometimes when I start my phone I get this "Optimizing app" thing that takes about 10 - 20 minutes for it to finish.

During this operation phone is unusable and reset doesn't help as the operation is repeated on next boot.

I am wondering, sometimes my nexus dies because of low battery. Now imagine there was a car accident and I needed to do emergency call. I could start it up using USB charger I have in my car, but what would I do if it got stuck because of this "Optimizing" thing?

Is there any way to cancel it so that I can do an emergency call?

Comment: AFAIK, "Optimizing app" only happens after OS update. Perhaps it's also happened on factory reset (I don't know, I never do factory reset). Other than that, the OS needs to optimize the app after the change from the update. Lastly, I don't see this can be bypassed, it's like stopping Windows while it's updating, which can be considered as dangerous (data corruption). If this happens often, then I'd consider that as bigger problem than what you ask here...

Comment: Yes, it happens very often to me when system dies improperly (that happens to me often, because of poor battery condition).

Comment: There is something really wrong with your phone if you keep getting that thing randomly (it shouldn't even happen if your phone dies of poor battery). On top of that, it really shouldn't be blocking your device for 10-20 minutes too. I'd recommend you to do a factory reset (or a full system reflash) on your device.